# Using multiple values in 1 Parameter of a Where statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using a query to fill a `TableAdapter` with the following query

```
SELECT Key1, Character01
FROM Ice.UD08
WHERE (Character01 IN (@MPS))
```

This works fine if I only pass 1 value through as the parameter (for example 1155) as seen in the code below

```
SELECT
    CASE grade
        CASE "1045"
            grade = "1155"
END SELECT 
Me.UD08TableAdapter.FillBy(Me.Epicor10DataSet.UD08, grade)
```

If I try and modify the code below to include multiple values like in the example below I get no results

```
SELECT
    CASE grade
        CASE "1045"
            grade = "1155,1160,1165"
END SELECT
Me.UD08TableAdapter.FillBy(Me.Epicor10DataSet.UD08, grade)
```

I am trying to pass a parameter that would essentially change the SQL statement to be as follows

```
SELECT Key1, Character01
FROM Ice.UD08
WHERE (Character01 IN (1155, 1160, 1165))
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a delimited list, for example `'1155,1160,1165'` then you'll need to split those values out. You can do so using `STRING_SPLIT`; thus your syntax would become:

```
SELECT Key1, Character01
FROM Ice.UD08
WHERE Character01 IN (SELECT [value]
                      FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourParameter));
```

An alternative approach, however, would be to use a User defined Table datatype. [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)